# How to know if a HTTP message is received completely or not

Tags: http, chunked-encoding

I am developing a small web server in C. The HTTP messages can come with content length or with chunked encoding. If it is coming with content length header, it is easy to know when the message is received completely.

When message comes chunk wise, or with binary attachments, how do we determine if the message is received completely or not.

I am planning to use http-parser for this and my sockets asynch in nature. Http-praser needs to be told when packet is completely received.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [He says a `chunk` with `size==0` is the sign.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4020165/2569323) And. [MDN also.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding)

Comment: https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#message.body.length should have all the information you need.